# Remote Desktop event ID 20499. No noticeable issues

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-terminal-services

I get a warning event with ID 20499 for TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager.The error is:

> Remote Desktop Services has taken too long to load the user configuration from server \server.domain.home for user administrator.

Yet, I don't see any issues (I'm guessing because that user is on the machine local). Why am I getting this warning?

I'm on Windows Server 2012 R2 connecting from a Windows 8.1.

Comment: Are you asking a question? I don't see a question, I see a statement.

Comment: What would trigger the warning?

Comment: Can you post the output of `Get-NetOffloadGlobalSetting`?

Comment: In order of "ReceiveSideScaling; ReceiveSegmentedCoalescing; Chimney; TaskOffload; NetworkDirect; networkDirectAcrossIPSubnets; PacketCoalescingFilter": Client `Enabled; Disabled; Disabled; Enabled; Disabled; Blocked; Enabled`. Server `Enabled; Enabled; Disabled; Enabled; Enabled; Blocked; Disabled`.

Comment: There is a thread on the MS boards about that. It has been going on since 2013. And no end in sight as of now (Feb 2016). Seems like a benign but annoying event. MS-Forums: [*Remote Desktop Services has taken too long to load the user configuration from server Event ID 20499*](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0dd2c0db-4eab-4e66-801d-76aeca59367a/remote-desktop-services-has-taken-too-long-to-load-the-user-configuration-from-server-event-id-20499?forum=winserverTS)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will solve your problem:

In Registry Editor, locate and then click one of the following registry subkeys:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services

Add DWORD fQueryUserConfigFromLocalMachine with value 1

restart

Reference
https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/help/4021856/sbsl-issue-when-you-create-an-rdp-connection-to-windows-server

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this can be triggered by using mRemote / Remote Desktop Connection Manager (RCDMan 2.2) or similar software.

The fix is to set `TaskOffload = Disabled` using [`Set-NetOffloadGlobalSetting`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826128.aspx)

Source: http://www.itnotes.eu/?p=1193

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. I both set TaskOffload to disabled in powershell, and disabled each TCP/IP offload feature on the adapter itself. I then restarted the server, but still get the same warning.

Comment: This is always the answer I read everywhere. But what does this "TaskOffload" do? And why does it trigger the warning when enabled? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: This didn't work.

Comment: The new url for Set-NetOffloadGlobalSetting is here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/set-netoffloadglobalsetting?view=win10-ps